# unable to identify the problem with this code

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am trying to print from 1 to 21. I used while loop but it runs infinite.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
       int i=0;
       while(i<20)
         printf(":%d",i+1);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You have the loop condition `i < 20`, but nowhere inside the loop do you modify `i`. There's no assignment to `i` inside the loop. So `i` will never change its value from `0`, which should be pretty clear from the output. Perhaps you should use a `for` loop instead?

Comment: `i`. `i` never changes.

Comment: your is not get incremented.

Comment: you need to increment the value of `i` with every iteration. Otherwise, the loof will run for infinity times.

Answer (score 3):

i+1 does not modify the variable i. This expression will only display the result of i+1. To actually increment the variable try this line instead.

```
printf(":%d",++i);
```

Comment: Maybe `++i` 'd be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print numbers up to 21 then this condition of the loop

```
while(i<20)
```

is incorrect. You should write at least

```
while(i<21)
```

taking into account the expression `i + 1` in the call of `printf`

```
printf(":%d",i+1);
```

The loop is infinite because within the loop the variable `i` is not being changed and always stays equal to `0` as it was initially set.

```
int i=0;
```

You could write the loop the following way

```
int i = 0;

while( i++ < 21 )
{
    printf(":%d", i);
}
```

Or

```
while( i < 21 )
{
    printf(":%d", ++i);
}
```

The first one loop is more readable.

Or if you want to output numbers up to 20 then the loop will look like

```
int i = 0;

while( i++ < 20 )
{
    printf(":%d", i);
}
```

Or

```
while( i < 20 )
{
    printf(":%d", ++i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not increasing the value of `i`, thus nothing will happen. Here `i` is increased by 1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int i=0;
   while(i<=20){
       printf(":%d",i+1);
       i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```